# Jekyll: <br> tags are converted to <br /> tags

Tags: html, tags, jekyll, kramdown

After building the website in **Jekyll**, all **`<br>`** tags contained in **kramdown** pages are converted to **`<br />`** tags.

Does anybody know how to prevent this?

Comment: @Cristóbal Díaz Álvarez  It is not a fix applied by Jekyll. It happens with kramdown pages only.  What version of XHTML do you refer to? W3C (X)HTML5 checker marks `<br />` as warning. I perfectly know differences between errors and warnings: I am just looking for a way to prevent the conversion of the tag.

Answer (score 0):

I guess is a fix applied by Jekyll. In html, the slash is optional, but in xhtml is mandatory.

`<br>` or `<br />` or `<br/>` in html -> https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-br-element

`<br />` or `<br/>` mandatory in xhtml -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML

Comment: For clarity, the slash is allowed, not optional, and [can actually cause harm](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values)

Comment: The W3C recommendations of both XHTML 1.0 and XHTML 1.1 were retired on 27 March 2018. In 2023 I would expect Jekyll to allow me to use <br> rather than the legacy <br />.

Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML